# install paid application in multiple device from itunes

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have a scenario in that I have paid application. If I download that app and install in my device using iTunes. I have few question regarding to that.

1. What if I install it in multiple devices?
2. Will iTunes takes care about this that the paid app can not be installed in multiple devices?
3. If no for second question should I have to manage this using some other way? In case plese tell me the preferable way.
4. Does iTunes deduct money from the account we have if we install it in multiple devices?
5. Will iTunes take care automatically that the app is getting installed in same device multiple time or in different devices?

I think there should be a way that we can not install a paid application in multiple devices by paying once.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple allows appstore customers to install apps they purchased on up to 5 devices. I'm not 100% sure, but I think by preventing this in a technical manner you'll violate some of your own appstore foobar agreements.

I cannot think of any feasible technical way to prevent this anyway. You can't tie the UDID to the users account because you receive no receipt for a "classic" appstore purchase (as opposed to an in-app purchase). So even if you implemented some sort of license managing system (including some servers to keep track of user accounts), you couldn't prevent that the user simply creates a new account with your system on another device, because you cannot link them in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can install paid apps on 5 Device, if those device are all using the same iTunes account.
Per 5 device you will only have to pay once for the app.